# bootstrap date and time picker not working on bootstrap-modal?

Tags: jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ I try to use bootstrap date and time picker 
in modal but its not working..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to provide more information, because that datepicker certainly works in Bootrap modals.

[Demo](http://codepen.io/Sinetheta/pen/Ftjwi/).

Are you using Bootstrap 2? Because that's what [bootstrap-datetimepicker](http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) is built on.